# asp dropdown selected index won't go beyond 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlist and I'm making selection of the second dropdown based on the selected index of the first one since both has different values I'm depending on selected index. But when I make selection it always selects 1 regardless whatever selection I make.

I have autopostback enabled and also have onselectedindexchanged property as shown in the below code. Don't get why it's not working.

ASP code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfaq1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlfaq1_SelectedIndexChanged">

</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2faq1" runat="server">

</asp:DropDownList>
```

c# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            ddlfaq1.Items.Add(new ListItem("level 1", "0"));
            ddl2faq1.Items.Add(new ListItem("level 1", "0"));
            ddlfaq1.Items.Add(new ListItem("level 2", "a"));
            ddl2faq1.Items.Add(new ListItem("level 2", "1"));
            ddlfaq1.Items.Add(new ListItem("level 3", "b"));
            ddl2faq1.Items.Add(new ListItem("level 3", "2"));
        }
    }
protected void ddlfaq1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddl2faq1.SelectedIndex = ddlfaq1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you re-populating the `DropDownList`s in `Page_Load`, or some other page-level event, before handling the `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: You have `Text="1"` in both second and third item in `ddl2faq1` that's why you see `1` is selected even when you select `2` in `ddlfaq1`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya please check the edit

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Your posted snippet works as it  should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change Text="2" at last item of dropdown 2 `<asp:ListItem Value="contact" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>`. I tested it worked

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfaq1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlfaq1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2faq1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="help" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="contact" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```